# Retrieve generated ID in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, triggers

I'm converting a ColdFusion Project from Oracle 11 to MS SQL 2008. I used SSMA to convert the DB including triggers, procedures and functions. Sequences were mapped to IDENTITY columns.

I planned on using INSERT-Statements like

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.my_id
values('val1', 'val2')
```

This throws an error since the table has a trigger defined, that AFTER INSERT writes some of the INSERTED data to another table to keep a history of the data.

Microsoft writes:

> If the OUTPUT clause is specified without also specifying the INTO
>   keyword, the target of the DML operation cannot have any enabled
>   trigger defined on it for the given DML action. For example, if the
>   OUTPUT clause is defined in an UPDATE statement, the target table
>   cannot have any enabled UPDATE triggers.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

I'm now wondering what is the best practice fo firstly retrieve the generated id and secondly to "backup" the INSERTED data in a second table.

Is this a good approach for the INSERT? It works because the INSERTED value is not simply returned but written INTO a temporary variable. It works in my tests as Microsoft describes without throwing an error regarding the trigger.

```
<cfquery>
DECLARE @tab table(id int);
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.my_id INTO @tab
values('val1', 'val2');
SELECT id FROM @tab;
</cfquery>
```

Should I use the OUTPUT clause at all? When I have to write multiple clauses in one cfquery-block, shouldn't I better use SELECT SCOPE_DENTITY() ?

Thanks and best,
Bernhard

Comment: What do you need to do with `@tab` after the insert? Just return the `ID` to CF? Did you try using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `OUTPUT`? Did you try using a stored procedure to do the same, instead of stuffing ad hoc SQL into `cfquery`?

Comment: I don't use @tab for more than returning the generated ID. I don't want to much code/to many statements in one CFQUERY-block. If I use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` I would no longer need `DECLARE` and `OUTPUT`. If I had a Procedure I still had to retriee the generated ID without disabling the trigger. So I assume `SELECT SCOPE_DENTITY()`it is.

Comment: @Bardware - My first question would be did you try using cfquery's [`result`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html) attribute and the `result.IDENTITYCOL` variable instead? cfquery uses SCOPE_IDENTITY internally last I checked.

Comment: Unless ColdFusion is smoking its lunch, you should be able to do this with just the `INSERT` line, and let an `INSTEAD OF` trigger do the heavy lifting for you. See my updated answer for something to test. The benefit of doing it this way is if you have a multi-row insert you can get all of the new ids instead of just the most recent one (`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` just returns a single scalar value).

Comment: Leigh, since I come from Oracle I didn't get used to use `IDENTITYCOL` as it did not return the generated ID but the ROWID. Thanks for the hint, I'll think of it.

Comment: @Bardware - Ah, makes sense. I think the `result` attribute should play well with triggers. But let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work - the row gets inserted, the instead of trigger returns the result, the after trigger doesn't interfere, and the after trigger logs to the table as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x1(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), x SYSNAME);

CREATE TABLE dbo.log_after(ID INT, x SYSNAME, 
  dt DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.x1_after
ON dbo.x1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.log_after(x) SELECT x FROM inserted;
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.x1_before
ON dbo.x1
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tab TABLE(id INT);

    INSERT dbo.x1(x)
        OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @tab
        SELECT x FROM inserted;

    SELECT id FROM @tab;
END
GO
```

Now, if you write this in your `cfquery`, you should get a row back in output. I'm not CF-savvy so I'm not sure if it has to see some kind of `select` to know that it will be returning a result set (but you can try it in Management Studio to confirm I am not pulling your leg):

```
INSERT dbo.x1(x) SELECT N'foo';
```

Now you should just move your after insert logic to this trigger as well.

Be aware that right now you will get multiple rows back for (which is slightly different from the single result you would get from `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`). This is a good thing, I just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
<cfquery name="qryInsert" datasource="db" RESULT="qryResults">
   INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2)
</cfquery>

<cfset id = qryResults.IDENTITYCOL>
```

Comment: Since [cfquery](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html) supports automatic retrieval of identity values, that is what I would try first.

Comment: I definitely like this better, if the `INSERT` is always going to be guaranteed to be one row. What if it is `INSERT INTO mytable SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL SELECT 2,3;`?

Comment: The `OUTPUT` clause would return a multirow recordset in that case, good point.

Comment: @Aaron - Last I checked, it is designed for single record inserts only, like in the example. (Scope_indentity() is used internally)  So you are right that multiple record inserts would require a different approach. **Edit** Bardware - Are you dealing with multples or single records like in the original post?

Comment: I'm not suggesting he's using multiple-row inserts. Just wanted to make sure it was clear so that other users with the same question aren't surprised when they use this method and only get one ID back, that's all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - (My previous post collided with Bardware's, but...) Gotcha, and it is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that's the first time I've seen someone use a merged approach like that instead of simply using the built-in PK retrieval and splitting it into separate database requests ([example](http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2011/01/getting-generated-key-from-query-in.html)).

Comment: Since links can break over time, you might want to update your post to include a code snippet or two.